# Use a function to represent positive real numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Is it correct to define the positive real numbers as $\{f(x) = x^2\mid x \in \mathbb R\}$?

Comment: You probably mean $\{x^2\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. That is a description of the set of *non-negative* reals.

Comment: The image of $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{|x|}$ will give you all positive reals.

Comment: @David: Of course this wasn't mentioned in the question, but if you're going to start nitpicking and remove points from the domain of the function, why not the identity function on the positive reals and that's it?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use such that $\{x\in \Bbb R: x>0\}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\{y^2:y \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{x^2:x \in \mathbb{R}\}\}
$$

Comment: Maybe try to explain why this is an answer to the question?

Comment: @David-Holden This is clever.

Answer (score 1):

Try the exponential function. Paul, he wanted to do it using a function.

Comment: f(x)=x is also a function ;)

Comment: Why is this half a comment? Comments go to the comments, answers go to the answers.

Comment: Also, it's not clear that E wanted to do it using a function. Here is a reason why E might have not: $x^2$ has the advantage over $e^x$ that it is defined completely algebraically, showing that we can build the topology from the algebraic structure.